# Edit Java source code before compile

Tags: gradle

I am new to gradle. I am looking forward to migrating from maven to gradle. 
I had few requirements:

1. Existing project is maven based, and is generating a fat jar/uber jar. I am planning to split this into multiple projects, and creating smaller/thinner jars/libraries
   I am currently evaluating the Multi-project Build support.
2. I have to also edit the Java source code, automatically, like making the java source modifications based on certain conditions
3. Publish the project as maven based, as other projects which need these split-up jars are still maven based.

I suppose Maven plugin can be used for publishing?
Would Gradle be a good, scalable solution for these two requirements which I am looking into currently?
Also please provide some pointers around these two topics.

Comment: what is the question then?

Comment: *[..] making the java source modifications based on certain conditions [...]* That sounds bad. Really bad.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen exactly, I thought the same thing, but you never know, people got crazy ideas.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen well Project Lombok kinda does it. which is used in a lot of projects.

Answer (score 1):

1. Gradle has very good multi-project support, far better than Maven's. You can start with [this documentation section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)
2. You can setup compilation of generated/auto-edited sources as well. Take a look at [this forum post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-use-gradle-with-generated-sources/9401), discussing compilation of sources created from database using `hbm2dao`
3. You can setup publishing of projects using the Maven plugin. `pom.xml` files will be generated automatically